# Angular-Mock override parent directive and mock it

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to mock a directive that resides on the same module of it's parent.
Since i want to isolate the test to just the child directive i am trying to mock the parent. 
It would be easily feasible if they both resided on different modules but since they are on the same i get multiple directives with the same name.
To bypass that i tried to put something like this on my mock directive:

```
        return {
                priority: 100,
                terminal:true,
                restrict:'CE',
                scope:{
                    zoom:'@'
                },
                template:'<div ng-transclude></div>',
                controllerAs:'parentController',
                controller:mockController,
                transclude: true
            };
```

The problem is that while i can override the parent directive doing so, the child directive is never called since it has a lower priority and terminal will halt the execution.

What i am in search of is a way to override a directive definition while testing on karma-jasmine and using angular.mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a directive it automatically creates a factory and put the directive on an array so multiple directives can respond to the same markup.

[This person](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/angular-testing-directives) got a way of making it working by creating a service with the name of the directive.Unfortunately probably due to angular changes his solution didn't solved it for me yet because angular was demanding a $$bindings key on the directive and $$moduleName, adding those to the factory solved it .

I got it to mock like this:

```
    angular.mock.module('theModuleIWantToTest');
    angular.mock.module(function($provide){
        $provide.factory('mockParentDirective', function(){
                var directive={
                    priority:0,
                    name:'mockParent',
                    restrict:'CE',
                    scope:{
                        zoom:'@'
                    },
                    template:'<div ng-transclude></div>',
                    controllerAs:'mockParentController',
                    controller:mockController,
                    transclude: true,
                    $$moduleName:'theModuleIWantToTest',
                    $$bindings:{}
                };
                return [directive];
            }
        );

    });
```

In which mockParent was a previously declared directive that i want to override.

I don't think this is the best way but for now it is the only way i found to override a directive on Angular 1.4.2